# Watir handling multiple popups one after another

Tags: java, internet-explorer, popup, alert, watir

I have a scenario wherein on clicking one button, a first pop appears on the screen with a ok and a cancel button. On clicking the ok button of the first pop up, the second pop appears with a ok and a cancel button.

The issue here is I'm not able to click on the ok button of the second pop up.

The code used for clicking is below. The first pop up ok button is clicked successfully.

```
browser.button(:text, "Try it").click_no_wait

browser.alert.ok #here first alert ok button is clicked
```

If I use `browser.alert.ok` again for second alert, script hangs

Comment: Add tags about technologies which you use.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The problem appears to be how Watir-Classic handles waiting for the alert to disappear. When you execute `browser.alert.ok`, it will click the button and then call `wait_until_not_exists`:

```
def wait_until_not_exists
  Wait.until(3) {!exists?}
  @container.page_container.wait
end
```

This method waits for the alert to disappear and then the browser to finish loading.

After some testing, it looks like the waiting for the browser to finish loading does not account for alerts being displayed. The alert prevents Watir from believing the page is loaded and will therefore eventually timeout.

**Workaround**

The best solution would probably to be some how update the Browser#wait method. However, I am not sure what to change or the implications.

An alternative would be to just monkey patch the wait_until_not_exists method. This method is used less and therefore likely a lower risk change. You can add the following monkey patch when requiring Watir-Classic:

```
require 'watir-classic'

module Watir
  class Alert
    def wait_until_not_exists
      Wait.until(3) {!exists?}
      unless @container.page_container.alert.exists?
        @container.page_container.wait
      end
    end   
  end
end
```

Here we have changed the wait method to only wait for the page to load if there are no other alerts present.

With this patch, your code to click the two alerts should work:

```
browser.alert.ok    
browser.alert.ok
```

Comment: This is now working . Thanks for the response - Deepika